# Possible to convert 2D string array into 2D char array?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

For a Connect Four project I am uploading a user's saved game. The file reader will only read the file into a String array though. Is there a possible way to convert a 2D string array into a 2D char array (because the entire game uses chars and it'll take too much to change everything over to strings)?

Please note that I need to convert 2D to 2D, not 2D to 1D or whatever results I usually find searching for this.

Comment: Please post an example of your input and output - I don't quite understand what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it some code that should accomplish that:

```
char[][] stringToChar(String[][] stringArray)
{
    char[][] charArray = new char[stringArray.length][stringArray[0].length]
    for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < stringArray[0].length; j++)
        {
            charArray[i][j] = stringArray[i][j].charAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to serialize and deserialize your data storage object to a string, write it to disk, and read it back.

What's cool about that approach is you can use it in general, for any class you might need to save and read back in the future.

Check this out:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm